# Solr DIH - field still exists although not defined anymore

Tags: solr, dih

I use DIH to load data from a sybase database to Solr. So far everything works well. Now I decided, that I don't want to load a certain field anymore.
So I deleted the following line
`<field column="BibCode" name="bibcode"/>`
in data-config.xml.
Then I deleted all data (/solr/update?stream.body=*:* and /solr/update?stream.body=), restarted tomcat and started a full import.
When I search now, the field bibcode still contains content and I don't understand where it comes from.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: >I use DIH to load data from a sybase database to Solr.< Did you have also changed the SQL statement for the import?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either remove the field from the `query` in your `data-config.xml` or remove it from `schema.xml`.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#A_shorter_data-config

Comment: I thought, I've already deleted it from schema.xml as well, but obviously I didn't. After removing the field from data-config.xml AND schema.xml, it works. Thanks!